# 'world' is protected, how do I get a pointer?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, super dumb question... I'm writing a sensor plugin (subclass SensorPlugin) that wraps an Altimeter sensor and I need access to SimTime(). How do I get a pointer to the world object to call SimTime()? I see it in the sensor API (include/gazebo-9/gazebo/sensors/Sensor.hh) but it's protected. Is there some magic global variable that I'm missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23823/%27world%27-is-protected,-how-do-i-get-a-pointer?/) by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's not recommended to access the world from a sensor plugin because sensors don't run in the physics thread.

Maybe what you want are `Altimeter::LastUpdateTime` or `Altimeter::LastMeasurementTime`?

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on 2019-09-24**:
Thanks for the quick reply! I suspected as much. `Altimeter::LastMeasurementTime` is always 0 and `Altimeter::LastUpdateTime` seems 10-20ms later than `ros_node->now()`, which itself is later than `Camera::LastMeasurementTime`. Any advice? Perhaps I need to write a camera sensor plugin that will give me consistent time across multiple sensors? Or fix `Altimeter::LastMeasurementTime`?

**Comment by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on 2019-11-23**:
My workaround (so far): I hacked up a version of gazebo_ros_pkgs that use wall time, rather than SimTime or ROS time. While not ideal, all sensors report the same time. If there are other good options I'd love to hear about them!